Implement an Expandable User Profile Section with Scrollable Widgets
I’m working on a Flutter home screen design and need some help with a specific feature. Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
Layout Design:

User Profile: This should take up 55% of the screen.
Tab Bar: Below the user profile, I have a tab bar with two tabs: "My Calendar" and "My Schedule."
Date-Time Widget & Filter Widget: These should be placed in a row right below the tab bar.
Schedule (Period List): Positioned below the date-time and filter widgets.

Expandable User Profile:

When dragging down on the user profile section, it should expand to cover the entire screen and reveal additional widgets (4-5 widgets). This expanded view should be scrollable.
When scrolling up, it should return to the default view (55% of the screen).
The expanded view should collapse back to the default view once all additional widgets are scrolled through.
Here’s a rough sketch of what I’m aiming for:

Expand Profile View

Collapse Profile View

My Questions:

How can I implement the expandable and collapsible functionality for the user profile section?
What is the best approach to ensure that the expanded view is scrollable and collapses when all widgets are scrolled through?
Are there any recommended Flutter widgets or libraries that could help with this functionality?


Use something like Expansion Tile for that. Below is just a general example :
The indentation may be not proper for code because writing it via phone but i have provided most of the properties that you can use in your case.

ExpansionTile(
                             
collapsedBackgroundColor: nyanza,
                                backgroundColor: nyanza,
                                textColor: text,
                                collapsedTextColor: text,
                                collapsedIconColor: text,
                                iconColor: text,
                                title: const Text(
                                    'Take Quiz by Searching Quiz Title'),
                                collapsedShape: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.transparent)),
                                shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.transparent)),
                                onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isExpandedTitle = value;
                                  });
                                },
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  if (isExpandedTitle)
                                    //show expanded view,
                         if(!isExpandedTitle) // show normal view
                                   ],),

